# What group is being referred to when vectors are said to be conjugate?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

In Linear Algebra, two vectors $x$ and $y$ are said to be conjugate with respect to a matrix $B$ if and only if

$$
x^{T}By = 0
$$

In group theory two elements $a, b \in G$ are said to be conjugate if there exists $g \in G$ such that

$$
b = g^{-1}ag
$$

So my question is as follows. When talking about conjugate vectors, what group are we referring to? What is the set and what is the group operation? If I take $a = x$ and $b = y$ can I derive the appropriate $g \in G$ from $B$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never heard of the term "conjugate" used in linear algebra that way, and the definition you've given is not a special case of the group theory definition. In particular, it is not an equivalence relation.  For example, take $B$ to be the identity matrix, then we have just $x^T y = 0$ which means the two vectors are perpendicular in the usual Euclidean space.  Perpendicularity is not an equivalence relation because it is not transitive.  Even in 3 dimensions, you can easily find two vectors perpendicular to a fixed vector that are not perpendicular to each other.

Comment: Maybe I should have been more specific with where I have seen it. Specifically the most common place I have seen this definition of conjugate turn up is in [Conjugate gradient methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method). I know the term conjugate is fairly overloaded in mathematics, so perhaps the "conjugate" used in this setting is not the same as the group theoretic one?

Comment: I see. That use of "conjugate" is definitely not related to the group theory use. It's also IMHO a rather odd use of the word. In most other uses, "conjugate" suggests either an equivalence relation (as in the group theory use) or a pairing of elements (as in "complex conjugate"). But in your example, it is neither.  Perhaps it came from the 2 dimensional case, where each direction has only one perpendicular direction so there is a pairing.